# Javascript how to round a whole number up and find its addition value?

Tags: javascript, luhn

**Goal**

I am at the final stage of scripting a Luhn algorithm.

**Problem**

Let's say I have a final calculation of `73`

How can I round it up to the next `0`? So the final value is `80`.

And lastly, how can I get the value that made the addition? e.g. `7` is the final answer.

**Current code**

```
function validateCred(array) {
  // Array to return the result of the algorithm
  const algorithmValue = [];

  // Create a [2, 1, 2] Pattern
  const pattern = array.map((x, y) => {
    return 2 - (y % 2);
  });

  // From given array, multiply each element by it's pattern
  const multiplyByPattern = array.map((n, i) => {
    return n * pattern[i];
  });

  // From the new array, split the numbers with length of 2 e.g. 12 and add them together e.g. 1 + 2 = 3
  multiplyByPattern.forEach(el => {
    // Check for lenght of 2
    if(el.toString().length == 2) {
      // Split the number
      const splitNum = el.toString().split('');
      
      // Add the 2 numbers together
      const addSplitNum = splitNum.map(Number).reduce(add, 0);

      // Function to add number together
      function add(accumalator, a) {
        return accumalator + a;
      }
      algorithmValue.push(addSplitNum);
    }

    // Check for lenght of 1
    else if(el.toString().length == 1){
      algorithmValue.push(el);
    }
  });

  // Sum up the algorithmValue together 
  const additionOfAlgorithmValue = algorithmValue.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  });

  // Mod the final value by 10
  if((additionOfAlgorithmValue % 10) == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}

// Output is False
console.log(validateCred([2,7,6,9,1,4,8,3,0,4,0,5,9,9,8]));
```

**Summary of the code above**

The output should be `True`. This is because, I have given the total length of 15 digits in the array. Whereas it should be 16. I know the 16th value is `7`, because the total value of the array given is 73, and rounding it up to the next 0 is 80, meaning the check digit is 7.

**Question**

How can I get the check number if given array length is less than 15?

Comment: If you mod 73 by 10 you get a remainder.... 80 does not... i think this is a start and the whole idea on which you should proceed.

Comment: Yes you're right. But if I have added an 7 at the end of an array, that will give me 80. But my struggle right now is, how do I work out the 7 within the code. Because the total length of an array should equal to 16 including the check digit. If 15 were given, I need to find the check digit.

Comment: Use the modulus as @PeterDarmis said `10-(73%10) = 7`

Comment: @pilchard that makes alot of sense! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
let x = [73,81,92,101,423];

let y = x.map((v) => {
let remainder = v % 10;
let nextRounded = v + (10-remainder);
/* or you could use 
let nextRounded = (parseInt(v/10)+1)*10; 
*/
let amountToNextRounded = 10 - remainder;
return [nextRounded,amountToNextRounded];
});

console.log(y);
```

**EDIT**

As noticed by [@pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) you could find `nextRounded` using this more simplified way:

```
let nextRounded = v + (10-remainder);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard

Comment: `nextRounded` is just `v + (10-remainder)`

Comment: @pilchard yes one way of finding nextRounded is the one you write and i think it is more simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you need is this:

```js
var oldNum = 73
var newNum = Math.ceil((oldNum+1) / 10) * 10;;
```

Then check the difference using this:

```js
Math.abs(newNum - oldNum);
```